# I am trying to change the font style of the Texarea based on what i select from the FontSelector Dialog using Javafx. this is my code

Tags: java, javafx, fonts, styles

This is my code and it opens a dialog and I want to change the textarea font size and style after I click OK.

```
public void ChangeFontStyle() {
    fontstyle.setOnAction(e -> {
            FontSelectorDialog fontSelectorDialog = new FontSelectorDialog(null);
            fontSelectorDialog.setTitle("Select Font");
            fontSelectorDialog.show();
            textarea.setFont(fontSelectorDialog.getResults());
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: You didn't describe your problem with the code. Most likely you should call `showAndWait` instead of `show` but without knowing what your `FontSelectorDialog` class looks like this is impossible to tell.

Comment: I know I didn't describe everything correctly but I think the showAndWait worked. Thank you so much